# Parsing math expression in gawk + gensub

Tags: regex, bash, awk, printf, gawk

I try to find all numbers in scientific notation and replace them to their floating point equivalent:

```
gawk -F' ' '
    BEGIN {
    OFMT = "%.0f"
    data = "\
    6.54321e2\n\
    6.543212\n\
    .\n\
    454.\n\
    c. 5.54321e2\n\
    5.54321e2 1.54321e3\n\
    4.54321e2 8.34e+4\n\
    4.543212 5.54321e2\n\
    3.23e3"
    regex = "([0-9]+).([0-9]+)e([0-9]+)"
    output = gensub(regex, "\\1.\\2e\\3", "G", data)
    printf("%.3f", output)
    }' "$1"
```

Replacing `printf("%.3f", output)` with `print b` seems to work fine, the numbers it found are replaced, but the printf parameter `output` is not parsed as it should. `strtonum()` did not change anything, am I missing something?

As you can see at the end, I do have also problems with assigning the file under script parameter `$1`. Should I point to the file as in a variable like `data` or explicitly in `gensub()`.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what `$1` is for, but you can do the following

```
echo "data contents here" | 
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i) $i=sprintf("%.3f",$i)}1'
```

or put your data in a file and use

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i) $i=sprintf("%.3f",$i)}1' file
```

it will normalize white space as a side effect.